# How can i forward a phone call on sim800 to a number using AT command

Tags: c, embedded, at-command, sim800

Hello everyone am trying to forward an incoming call on a gsm module, sim800f to a my other line.
I'm communicating with the gsm module over a serial to USB converter and Putty terminal.

The AT command provided by simcomn
AT+CCFC=reason,mode,"number",....

I've tried several all of the options given
AT+CCFC=0,3,"+3630xxxxxx"

But call doesn't get forwarded to the other line.
Are there steps that am missing?

Comment: Do you need a <type> = 145 parameter to indicate that it is an international number? i.e. `AT+CCFC=0,3,"+3630xxxxxx",145`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I do. Do I have to send this command soon as the module rings or soon as I pick the call?

Comment: I have no idea - just looking at the documentation - it is not great.

Comment: What kind of call do you need to forward? Voice calls only?

Comment: Yes, voice only calls